# React JS Tags and Attributes

Tags: reactjs

How do I make the div attributes React friendly?

```
 <div className="section-modal modal fade" id="pricing-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">

 </div>
```

I Tried:

```
 <div className="section-modal modal fade" id="service-modal" tabindex= {-1} role={dialog} aria-hidden={true}>
```

Comment: What do you mean react friendly?

Comment: Read document then ask question like this

Answer (score 1):

Strings should be enclosed in quotes, bools, numbers, variables, and objects in brackets. In your case it should be:

```
 <div className="section-modal modal fade" id="service-modal" tabindex={-1} role="dialog" aria-hidden={true}>
```

Read up more about jsx here:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html

Comment: Apart from the `dialog` value which I'm assuming the OP wants to pass down a string & not a variable. @AndrewLi React is probably trying to find the dialog variable and failing

Comment: What I'm saying is that it seems like those are pure HTML attributes, not variables in JS.

Answer (score 0):

**CamelCase is the problem in your HTML**

You should refer https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html#html-attributes

React only supports a set of HTML attributes given in the list and ignores the rest. All the attributes should be **camelcased** except **data-** and **aria-**. You HTML should look like this.

```
<div className="section-modal modal fade" id="pricing-modal" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">

 </div>
```